# How to spell check a pdf document?

Tags: pdf, ms-word, acrobat, spell-checking, adobe-indesign

Adobe Acrobat spell checking only affects comments, fields, and editable text, it does not affect content.

I want to spell check absolutely the entire document.

On the other hand, adobe spell checking is not entirely satisfactory (at least in Spanish) and I would like to be able to use the one used by Microsoft Word.

Is there a way that I can spell check a pdf (all content) using Microsoft technology?

Clarify that the pdf document is generated from Adobe Indesign, not from word. That is, it is not a document generated from Microsoft word.

Any solution?

Thank you.

Comment: You can spellcheck in InDesign before it is exported to PDF

Comment: Yes but. I want to use the speellcheck from Microsoft Word technology. Spellcheck in  spanish is not very good in InDesign.

Comment: You can add/change dictionary in InDesign in Preferences/Dictionary. I do not think MS Word dictionary is compatible with InDesign , but you can search for alternative Spanish dictionary in same format as InDesign uses

Comment: As this isn't a programming question, it's off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Can i do something about it with code? Is there any option to parse de pdf and spellcheck it with any Microsoft API?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

https://pdf2doc.com/

Once converted, you can use MS Word for your spell checking.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Format converters don't work well with complex documents.

The pdf documents are somewhat elaborate (they are made in indesign). Converting to word and back to pdf would cause them to lose the format.